# Alone I Smite. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> Less one, and my maker is often said to be the mightiest between us.
>
> Alone I smite, yet my greater does not.

Who am I?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> **sword** - Omitting the first letter gives us 'word.' The maker of a word can be a pen, which is said to be mightier than the sword.

Comment: I believe this is correct but can a **** actually smite on it's own though?

Comment: @Arth I think the "Alone" might be referring to the answer as opposed to "One Less" than the answer.

Comment: @AggieKidd If that's the case, what does the "greater" refer to?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain The "one less" as explained in the answer.

Comment: @AggieKidd Oh, I see.  The first line says the "one less" is mightiest, so mightiest = greater? I interpreted it as "alone" being the answer, and "greater" being something added to the answer, so there is a progression from "one less" -> "answer" -> "greater".

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain That would make sense too.

Answer (score 5):

One option:

> A ruler

Less one, and my maker is often said to be the mightiest between us.

> Remove the 'r', and you get rule. Often, those who make the rules seem to be greater than the rules themselves (and don't live by them).

Alone I smite, yet my greater does not.

> Rulers are often used to "smite" kids who misbehave in class.

Comment: The second explanation is shakey, and makes the intended answer make more sense. Great try though!

Answer (score 3):

I'll put my guess out there as a

> Golem

My reasoning:

Less one, and my maker is often said to be the mightiest between us.

> There are two ways I have read on deactivating a Golem: 
>  1. Remove the mystic scroll from its mouth (less one scroll) 
>  2. Remove the character א (*aleph*) from אמת (*emet*, "truth") to make מת (*met*, "dead") (more likely)
>  So less one character and the creator of the Golem (Rabbi, Elder, Judge, or Sage typically) is now mightier than a lump of clay

Alone I smite, yet my greater does not.

> First, though Golems were not created to "smite enemies" in all traditions - there is a definite leaning in Jewish Mythology towards Golems being created to defend Jewish communities and in pop culture most Golems I have seen lean strongly toward militaristic tools or monsters (with the exception of Disc World). Yet I would say the Rabbi is the greater, so the Golem *smites enemies alone*.

Comment: This is actually a very good creative answer drawing on Jewish mythology. I made some minor typographical/grammar edits, feel free to roll back if it's not representative of your intention.

Comment: @MarchHo Actually I was planning on adding the actually Hebrew when I had a chance so thanks

Answer (score 0):

Power is described as the ability to destroy.Thus the answer is minus one (-1)

Comment: I like the idea of exponents and -1 as an answer but you need to expand your explanation to show how it fits the given clues.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's:

> -1

Because:

Less one, and my maker is often said to be the mightiest between us.

> Less one is also minus one. "1" would therefore be "my marker". 1 is one "mightier" than -1 in fundamental mathematics because it preserves identity in multiplication.

Alone I smite, yet my greater does not.

> In addition -1 smites by taking one away from a number, whereas "my greater", zero, doesn't take anything away from a number in addition.